# Google Chrome extension internationalization, switch locale

Tags: internationalization, google-chrome-extension

I just implemented the [internationalization (i18n)](http://code.google.com/chrome/extensions/i18n.html) feature of google chrome in my extension. I have languages `de` and `en`. I named `de` as default in the manifest file:

```
"default_locale": "de"
```

No I want to test if `en` works but

```
"default_locale": "en"
```

has no effect on the language, it stays german. Any ideas?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It is still German because your browser locale is German. [Internalization API](https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/i18n#testing-win) has detailed instructions on how to switch your locale for testing (scroll to the middle of the page).